# Is jQuery automatically enqueued in Wordpress 3.6

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Before, to include jQuery in Wordpress you had to do this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

But, as a method to make sure jquery was not already loaded, some people would do this:

```
function sp_load_jquery() {
    // only use this method is we're not in wp-admin
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        // deregister the original version of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        // register it again, this time with no file path
        wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
        // add it back into the queue
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'sp_load_jquery');
```

Which is frowned upon by many, who argue Wordpress loads jQuery in noConflict mode.

But, my ultimate question is, it seems that in Wordpress 3.6+ jQuery is automatically enqueued by Wordpress. Can someone tell me if this is the case?

**EDIT**

Ok, so with the help and answer below, this is what I now have:

```
function sp_load_jquery() {
    if ( ! is_admin() && !wp_script_is( 'jquery' ) ) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sp_load_jquery');
```

The add_action loads the sp_load_jquery function when Wordpress fires the wp_enqueue_scripts hook. The function then checks if user is not viewing the admin (as jQuery is auto loaded there), and also checks that jQuery has not been loaded using the Wordpress `wp_script_js()` function. The function then de-registers jQuery with Wordpress, re-registers it using Google's CDN and then sends the Google version back to the queue.

But, if you don't want to use Google's CDN, just do this:

```
function sp_load_jquery() {
    if ( ! is_admin() && !wp_script_is( 'jquery' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sp_load_jquery');
```

Comment: It would be safer (future-proof) to just check if jQuery is already loaded, rather than assume it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample is not to make sure jQuery was not already loaded....it is more to guarentee the version of jQuery that does get loaded.

If you are writing a plugin, best to try to write it keeping in mind that wordpress will always update to the latest verion of jQuery for each release (this breaks a few plugins). Just always enqueue the jquery script (without re-registering it) and if it has already been enqueued there is no issue by doing it again.

edit:

To see if a script is enqueued, you can:

```
$wpScripts = new WP_Scripts()
if($wpScripts->query('jquery','enqueued')){
    //it is loaded
}

if($wpScripts->query('jquery','registered')){
    //it has been registered
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what is the best method to check if jQuery had been loaded, using php?

Comment: Ok, I guess I can use `wp_script_is` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is